# Is there a way to load file that is under templates folder on Django HTML?

Tags: python, django

I could load css file on Django html like this

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
```

I wonder why I can't load css file that is under templates folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Is there a way to load file that is under templates folder on Django HTML?

Why does Django wants me to put {% static "css/style.css" %} this format on all static files? Is it because much faster to load?

What If I load file that is under templates folder? Is it slow to load?

Comment: Try using the complete path, you could use `TEMPLATE_DIR` url in `settings` the call the `.css` file you want.

Comment: can you show me a sample complete path?

Comment: When you go into production you will serve the statics from other folder when you execute `collectstatic` command. I recommed you to put your css file under static folder and use `{% load static ... %}` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see it, you have missed the concept of the templates and the static files in Django.

First of all, there are two independent mechanisms: loading a template file (your future HTML file) and loading your static files (css, js, images).

When loading a template Django uses `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types)), which are basically defined in your `settings.py` as:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    # Loads templates from DIRS setting:
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 

    # Loads templates from your installed apps:
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader', 
)
```

You can define a location of yout templates by setting `DIRS` (if you are using Django >= 1.8) or `TEMPLATE_DIR` (if Django < 1.8). There are several more steps in rendering your template such as: template context processors and so on, but it is all listed in the documentation.

Now about static files.

Static files are served by `django.contrib.staticfiles` app ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)) when `DEBUG = True`. In production it is done by Nginx, Apache or other Http-Servers.
When loading a static file Django uses `STATICFILES_FINDERS`. They are usially defined as:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    # Loads static files from STATICFILES_DIRS:
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",

    # Load static files from installed apps:
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"
)
```

There are two main settings to care about: `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`.
`STATIC_URL` is basically just a prefix, which is used to get your static files. It is almost always just `'/static/'`. And in `STATICFILES_DIRS` there are paths to your static files folders. It is sometimes extended to include `node_modules`, `bower_components` or things like that.

When dealing with static files in templates you need to append your `STATIC_URL` to your file's URL. The easiest way to do that is `{% static %}` tag.

A lot of confusion comes with `STATIC_ROOT`. It is just a path, where all your static files will be collected in production after running `collectstatic` management command.

Answer (score 5):

Templates and static assets are two differents types of assets that need to be managed differently for security purposes.

All js, css and images files need to be provided to clients in order for your website to be working. They are handled from the client side so they need to be available. So static asset folder is made to be available, if you check view source and follow the link of these assets you'll see they can be opened directly in your broswer.

Templates however are used by django itself to generate the output that is set via your views. When a user opens a page, he doesn't access the template itself but the rendering made by django. So the template folder isn't accessible to end user by design, including the files that are in it. So the only things a user can access from a django application are the responses given by the views, that are based on urls patterns and the templates, and assets that are in static folder. So you can't, and shouldn't, link to static assets from anywhere else but your static folder.